# Transversality just on a single point but not in any neighborhood

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, transversality

I just learned the concept of Transversality. Briefly, let $f:M \to N$ be a smooth map and $A \subset N$ be a submanifold. If $K \subset M$ we write $f \pitchfork_K A$ to mean that $f$ is transverse to $A$ along $K$, that is, whenever $x\in K$ and $f(x) = y\in A$, the tangent space $T_yN$ is spanned by $T_y A$ and the tangent image of $T_xM$ or
$$
f_{*x}(T_xM)+T_yK=T_yN.
$$

Obviously, Transversality is a local concept. So I wonder is it possible that $f\pitchfork A$ just on a point but not in any neighborhood of $x$. Formally speaking, Can we choose smooth manifolds $M,N$, a smooth map $f:M \to N$ and a submanifold $A\subset N$ such that there exists a point $x\in M$, $f\pitchfork_x A$ but there is no neighborhood $U$of $x$ satisfying $f\pitchfork_U A$.

Additionnaly, what condition can garuntee such $U$ exists?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It should be $T_yA$ instead of $T_y K  $ in your formula. 
Try to do this locally (in charts) and use that the determinant is continuous.